# How do you import a DevOps build?

Tags: build, azure-devops

I want to take a build from one #DevOps project and put it on another project.  I see how to export the build to JSON, but don't see a way to import it.

I have seen another SO question on how to do this for releases, but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2):

Go to builds and select "+ New" and select "Import a pipeline" there:

[image]

Comment: I want to import a build, not a pipeline.  I have exported a build.  Can believe I tried to import a build into a pipeline, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: that doesnt make any sense, what do you mean import a build?

Comment: I guess it's just terminology.  I mean import a build definition which is probably the same thing as a pipeline.  I do see the import a pipeline option on the Builds tab after I have created at least one "pipeline".  I have imported one and all looks good except the trigger is based off of the wrong repo.  Maybe I need to change the JSON file before importing it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your build pipeline and edit the build. Then you can display the complete list of tasks for your agent jobs as **YAML file**.
[image: Azure DevOps - export build tasks as YAML file]

Now save the YAML file as document of the type .yaml in your Code repo.

Then you can create a new build pipeline in DevOps and include your previously exported YAML file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, i needed to export builds from TFS 2015 to TFS 2017.
In order to achieve that i used this extension :

> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onlyutkarsh.ExportImportBuildDefinition

I also wrote a script who export build from one project and import to other project automatically .
Let me know if you want me to add this script as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible.

It's easy to get a build through API to a json file.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=5.0
```

However, it's not able to import this build back or to another pipeline. This is also not make sense.

As a workaround, suggest you directly clone the build pipeline and queue it again. Which may do the trick.